# Not able to create MultiRNN cell in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to create a RNN for generating the next words below is the code

When I give only the BasicLSTMCell, I am not getting errors and getting expected output

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(name="X", shape=[None, 3, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(name="Y", shape=[None, uniqueWordsLength], dtype=tf.float32)


Xs = [tf.squeeze(seq, [1]) for seq in tf.split(X, 3, 1)]
print(len(Xs))

n_cells=200
n_layers=2
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_cells, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1.0)
initial_state = cells.zero_state(tf.shape(X)[0], tf.float32)
outputs, states =  tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

However when I add the Multi RNN Cell with two layers as below, I am getting an error

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(name="X", shape=[None, 3, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(name="Y", shape=[None, uniqueWordsLength], dtype=tf.float32)


Xs = [tf.squeeze(seq, [1]) for seq in tf.split(X, 3, 1)]
print(len(Xs))

n_cells=200
n_layers=2
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_cells, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1.0)
initial_state = cells.zero_state(tf.shape(X)[0], tf.float32)
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cells] * n_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, states =  tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The error is

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 400 and 201 for 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,400], [201,800].
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `MultiRNNCell`, you need to create *distinct* cells for each layer. In your code, you are essentially trying to reuse the exact same cell `n_layers` times. This can lead to issues e.g. when the dimensionality of the input is different from what the cell outputs. Aside from that, it's not recommended anyway since each layer would use the same parameters.

Instead, create distinct cells like this:

```
cell_list = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_cells, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1.0) 
         for _ in range(n_layers)]
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell_list, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its correct. Unfortunately in most learning sites
, this information is not available

Comment: There was a slight mistake; you need to use `range(n_layers)` of course assuming that's an int.

Comment: Yes we need to give range(n_layers)